# Conflicting dates in mongoose and express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, momentjs

The problem occurs when I declare my schema with type Date rather than String.

Case I:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    created_at: {type: String, default: ''}
});
```

With this shema declaration I use moment.js `moment-timezone` module for declaring current time in Asia/Kolkata timezone.

```
var tmoment = require('moment-timezone');
var currentTime = tmoment().tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('llll');
```

And I am able to get the correct time.

Case II:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    created_at: {type: Date, default: ''}
});
```

With this shema declaration I use moment.js `moment-timezone` module for declaring current time in Asia/Kolkata timezone.

```
var tmoment = require('moment-timezone');
var currentTime = tmoment().tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('llll');
```

**But** now the time is not coming according to the timezone. I even tried with the following declaration

```
var tmoment = require('moment-timezone');
var currentTime = tmoment().tz('Asia/Kolkata').format();
```

**But** could not find a solution.

Comment: Can you provide any more context? I set this up locally and it worked correctly.

Comment: calling `format()` will output a string. so try `var currentTime = tmoment().tz('Asia/Kolkata')` which will give a date object

Comment: @mani I tried doing that but it is giving me datetime like `2016-04-13T11:39:27.942Z` whereas according to case I it is returning `Wed, Apr 13, 2016 5:09 PM`

Comment: could you post your mongoose hook code for setting created_at

Comment: `var saveReq = new RequestModel({ created_at: currentTime });` and then `saveReq.save(function(err, result) {if(err) //condition for error});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are saving dates to a mongo database, you can simply save a javascript `Date` object regardless of timezone. (Using the `Date` type as in case 2.) Then you would use moment to **display** the date in whatever timezone you require.

To save the object:

```
var id = ...
var saveReq = new RequestModel({ _id: id, created_at: new Date() });
saveReq.save(function (err, result) {
  // ...
});
```

To read the object from the database, and then display the localized date string:

```
var tmoment = require('moment-timezone');
RequestModel.findOne({_id: id}, function (err, doc) {
  if(err) {} // ...
  var created = doc.created_at;
  var display = tmoment(created).tz('Asia/Kolkata').format('llll');
  console.log(display);
});
```

Comment: I think this solution will pretty much solve my problem of filtering data between two dates as well as I can change the dates from a particular timezone to the standard js format and then apply my filter logic. Thanks man. !! Great help. !

Answer (score 0):

change server timezone to your local timezone.